# How do I find the point intersecting a line?

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, graphics, 2d

If I have the following chart in Flutter:

[image: graph]

Where the green graph is a `Path` object with many `lineTo` segments, how do I find the y-coordinate for a point with a given x-coordinate?

As you can see in the image, there is a gray dotted line at a specific point on the x-axis and I want to draw a point where it intersects with the green graph.

---

Here is an example path:

```dart
final path = Path();
path.moveTo(0, 200);
path.lineTo(10, 210);
path.lineTo(30, 190);
path.lineTo(55, 150);
path.lineTo(80, 205);
path.lineTo(100, 0);
```

And I want to find the y-coordinate for the point at `dx = 75`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this for **any** path that only has a single point for every `x` (i.e. where there is only a single graph / line from left to right) is using the [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

You can then simply use the distance of the path, which is obtained using [`Path.computeMetrics`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PathMetric/computeMetrics.html), to perform binary search and find the offset via [`Path.getTangentForOffset`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/PathMetric/getTangentForOffset.html):

```dart
const searchDx = 75;
const iterations = 12;
  
final pathMetric = path.computeMetrics().first;
final pathDistance = pathMetric.length;
late Offset closestOffset;
var closestDistance = pathDistance / 2;
for (var n = 1; n <= iterations; n++) {
  closestOffset = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(closestDistance)!.position;
  if (closestOffset.dx == searchDx) break;
   
  final change = pathDistance / pow(2, n);
  if (closestOffset.dx < searchDx) {
    closestDistance += change;
  } else {
    closestDistance -= change;
  }
}
  
print(closestOffset); // Offset(75.0, 193.9)
```

Note that if you want to run significantly more iterations (which should not be necessary due to the nature of binary search), you should replace `final change = pathDistance / pow(2, n);` by a cheaper operation like storing the left and right points of your current search interval.

---

You can find the full working code as an [example on Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=35ecfe134a5197ec7f727a9957a13b3c).